# Play Framework - how to change the label of a input when using form helpers?

Tags: forms, scala, web, playframework

If I use the `form` helper to get a `loginForm` at my site, how can I customize the input label? Of course, the label which is set is the name of the variable in my Java class. However, I want another label name than the variable name.

At this point the only way to change it, I found, is to set up a completely new form builder. In this, I look if the element I want to illustrate is the element I want to set a new label and then set the other label. However, I think this is very much overdone.

Is there an easy variable I can add at the end of the `@helper.input` statement to change the label name?

I am using PlayFramework 2.6.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. You just need to add a `'_label` parameter in our input. For example:

```
@(userForm: Form[User])

@helper.form(action = routes.UsersController.save()) {
    @helper.inputText(userForm("name"), '_label -> "Your name")
    @helper.inputText(userForm("email"), '_label -> "Your E-mail")
}
```

Pay attention that it has a `'` only at the start. This is documented here:

https://playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaFormHelpers

Another way to do that, if you need to highly customized the generate HTML is by [handling HTML input creation yourself](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaFormHelpers#Handling-HTML-input-creation-yourself).

Comment: Thank you very much, this was an very nice answer. I saw this, however thougt that these are only fit in the Formbuilder :)